# call pageload event in aspx pages of a .vb page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pageload

i have many aspx pages in one folder (100 pages) and they will keep increasing. I have 1 vb.net file which has the code for these pages. Can i call that pageload event in vb.net file from all these pages?
currently im using this code, but its not reading the pageload event.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       newone_load(page)
    End Sub
</script>
```

vb.net page code -

```
Public Module NewOne
    Public Sub NewOne_Load(ByRef Page As Web.UI.Page)
    end sub
end module
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a small error in your code: Add `Handles Me.Load` to your Page_Load sub

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Else the sub will never be bound to the Load event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("works")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to use one code-behind file for many ASPX pages. You can do this by specifying the CodeBehind and Inherits properties in the @Page directive of the ASPX files:

```
<%@ Page ...CodeBehind="MasterCodeBehind.ascx.vb" Inherits="MasterCodeBehind" ...%>
```

You don't need to call Page_Load in your client-side markup. The Page_Load method in MasterCodeBehind will be called on page load.